# Rails How to resolve Error File name too long @ rb_sysopen

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app where I can generate reports and when I'm trying to generate one I have this error Error File name too long @ rb_sysopen and a very long stuff see below. What I want to understand what could be the reason of this error. What should I look?

```
Errno::ENAMETOOLONG at /study_versions/2/export_acrf.2
File name too long @ rb_sysopen - /Users/jakublemiszewski/Desktop/A3informatics/Tourmalet/Tourmalet/public/<html><head><style>h1 { font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24pt; line-height: 34pt; }
h1.title { font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24pt; line-height: 30pt; text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }
h2 { font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt; line-height: 28pt; }
```

This continues for many rows in the error message.

However, I have no idea where to look I spent hours to understand and cannot see a solution for it.

I believe the error comes from this class:

```
class PdfReport

  C_CLASS_NAME = "PdfReport"

  def self.create(title, sub_title, user, body_html)
    paper_size = "A4"
    html = page_header()
    html += title_page(title, sub_title, user)
    # Document history
    html += body_html
    # Completion instructions
    html += page_footer()
    #ConsoleLogger.log(C_CLASS_NAME, "create", "HTML=" + html.to_s)
    # pdf = WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(html, :page_size => paper_size, :footer => {:font_size => "10", :font_name => "Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif", :left => "", :center => "", :right => "[page] of [topage]"} )
    cls = [{:status=> ["created", "no_change", "updated"], :prefered_term => "test term", :notation => "This is test notation" }]
    results = [{ bc_demo: 'demo'}]
    pdf = CdiscChangesReport.new.create(results, cls, User.last, html)
    return pdf
  end

  def self.page_header
    html = "<html><head>"
    html += "<style>"
    html += "h1 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24pt; line-height: 34pt; }\n"
    html += "h1.title { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24pt; line-height: 30pt; text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }\n"
    html += "h2 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt; line-height: 28pt; }\n"
    html += "h2.title { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt; line-height: 24pt; text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }\n"
    html += "h3 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 16pt; }\n"
    html += "h4 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14pt; }\n"
    html += "h5 { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; }\n"
    html += "p { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; }\n"
    html += "table tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.simple { border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.simple tr td { border: 1px solid black; font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.simple tr th { border: 1px solid black; font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table h4 { vertical-align: middle;}\n"
    html += "table.form_table td:first-child{ font: bold; }\n"
    html += "table.form_repeat { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.form_repeat th { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; }\n"
    html += "table.form_repeat tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top;}\n"
    html += "table.details tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 11pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 1px; }\n"
    html += "table.ci { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;}\n"
    html += "table.ci tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; padding: 5px; border-bottom: 1pt solid black; }\n"
    html += ".ci td table, .ci td table tbody, .ci td table td { border:none; }\n" # Stops inheritence into markdown
    html += "table.note { border: 1px solid black; width: 100%;}\n"
    html += "table.note tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; font: bold; text-align: left; vertical-align: top; }\n"
    html += "table.input_field { border-left: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black; border-bottom: 1px solid black;}\n"
    html += "table.input_field tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 8pt; text-align: center; vertical-align: center; padding: 5px; }\n"
    html += "table.input_field td:not(:last-child){border-right: 1px dashed}\n"
    html += "table.cl_field tr td { font-family: Arial, \"Helvetica Neue\", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 10pt; text-align: left; vertical-align: center; padding: 2px; }\n"
    html += "table.cl_field td:first-child{ border: 1px solid black; }\n"
    html += "tr.warning { background-color: #fcf8e3 !important; }\n"
    html += "</style>"
    html += "</head><body>"
    return html
  end

  def self.page_footer
    html = "</body></html>"
    return html
  end

  def self.title_page(title, sub_title, user)
    name = ENV['organization_title']
    image_file = ENV['organization_image_file']
    dir = Rails.root.join("app", "assets", "images")
    file = File.join(dir, image_file)
    time_generated = Time.now
    # Generate HTML
    html = "<br><br><div style=\"text-align: center;\"><img src=\"#{file}\" style=\"height:75px;\"></div>"
    html += "<h2 class=\"title\">#{name}</h2>"
    html += "<br>" * 10
    html += "<h1 class=\"title\">#{title}<br>#{sub_title}</h1>"
    html += "<br>" * 23
    html += "<table class=\"details\" align=\"right\"><tr><td>Run at:</td><td>#{time_generated.strftime("%Y-%b-%d, %H:%M:%S")}</td></tr><tr><td>Run by:</td><td>#{user.email}</td></tr></table>"
    html += page_break
    return html
  end

  def self.page_break
    return "<p style='page-break-after:always;'></p>"
  end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

File systems have limits to the length of the path of the filename. Your error shows that you're naming your file with the contents of your file, which is probably why you're hitting this limit.

From your error message, here is your attempted filename:

```
/Users/jakublemiszewski/Desktop/A3informatics/Tourmalet/Tourmalet/public/<html><head><style>h1 { font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24pt; line-height: 34pt; }
h1.title { font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 24pt; line-height: 30pt; text-align: center; margin-top: 0; }
h2 { font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 18pt; line-height: 28pt; }
```

Giving your file a proper name should resolve your issue.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the tip. But what file I need to rename? Where I have to give a proper name? I cannot understand that @Daniel

Comment: How is the file generated? In `CdiscChangesReport` maybe? Are you pass the correct arguments to it?